# Multi-module maven build : different result from parent and from module

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am migrating an application from ant build to maven 3 build. 
This app is composed by :

- A parent project specifying all the modules to build
- A project generating classes with jaxb and building a jar with them
- A project building an ejb project
- 3 projects building war modules
- 1 project building an ear

**Here is an extract from my parent pom :**

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>P</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>04.01.00</version>

<modules>
    <module>../PValidationJaxb</module> <-- jar
    <module>../PValidation</module> <-- ejb
    <module>../PImport</module> <-- war
    <module>../PTerminal</module> <-- war
    <module>../PWebService</module> <-- war
    <module>../PEAR</module> <-- ear
</modules>
```

I have several problems which I think have the same origin, probably a dependency management issue that I cannot figure out :

- The generated modules are different depending on if I build from the parent pom or a single module. Typically if I build PImport only, the generated war is similar to what I had with my ant build and if I build from the parent pom, my war took 20MB, a lot of dependencies from other modules had been added. Both wars are running well.
- My project PWebService has unit tests to be executed during the build. It is using mock-ejb which has cglib as dependency. Having a problem of ClassNotFound with this one, I had to exclude it and add a dependency to cglib-nodep (see last pom extract). If I then build only this module, it is working well. But if I build from the parent project, it fails because other dependencies in other modules also had an implicit dependency on cglib. I had to exclude it in every modules pom and add the dependency to cglib-nodep everywhere to make it run.

Do I miss something important in my configuration ?

**The PValidation pom extract :**

It is creating a jar containing an ejb with interfaces generated by xdoclet, as well as a client jar.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>P</artifactId>
    <version>04.01.00</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>P-validation</artifactId>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>P-jaxb</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.ga</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
    [other libs]
    ...
</dependencies>

<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>2.0</ejbVersion>
                <generateClient>true</generateClient>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>xdoclet-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            ...
```

**The PImport pom extract :**

It depends on both Jaxb generated jar and the ejb client jar.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>P</artifactId>
    <version>04.01.00</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>P-import</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>P-jaxb</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>P-validation</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>ejb-client</type>
    </dependency>
    ...
    [other libs]
    ...
</dependencies>
```

**The PWebService pom extract :**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>P</artifactId>
    <version>04.01.00</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>P-webservice</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <jersey.version>1.14</jersey.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rte.etso</groupId>
        <artifactId>etso-validation</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>ejb-client</type>
    </dependency>
    ...
    [other libs]
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockejb</artifactId>
        <version>0.6-beta2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib-full</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Many thanks

**Solution after modification of the configuration :**

When I got the projects already mavenized, it didnt respect the folder layout convention, but as it was declared in the pom where to find the sources, I thought it would be working.
Anyway, i changed it to match the recommended structure.

To build a single module I was executing mvn clean install directly at its level. It is this way I obtained a different result (which is in fact the one I wanted).

Anyway, my problem is solved, I put all the dependencies of the PValidation project as provided, as I am only including the generated client in other modules and they dont require all what is needed for the implementation.

But still I dont get why I had different result for the same configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first important thing is you should create the structure of your project appropriate to the modules structure which means having the following folder structure:

```
+-- parent
      +-- PValidationJaxb
      +-- PValidation
      +-- PImport
      +-- PTerminal
      +-- PWebService
      +-- PEAR
```

This means having a pom.xml which contains the modules definition in the parent folder.
if you follow the above recommendation you can simplify the modules list to the following:

```
<modules>
    <module>PValidationJaxb</module> <-- jar
    <module>PValidation</module> <-- ejb
    <module>PImport</module> <-- war
    <module>PTerminal</module> <-- war
    <module>PWebService</module> <-- war
    <module>PEAR</module> <-- ear
</modules>
```

Furthermore a best practice in Maven is to use **lowercase artifacts** which mean in your case **pvalidationjaxb** instead of **PValidationJaxb**.

An other important thing is your version which does NOT follow the [Maven conventions](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/version-rules.html). Furthermore your version will be from the Maven point of view a release which is not the case you are doing development on this. In Maven you should use a so called **SNAPSHOT** for such purposes like 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

I hope you have followed the [folder layout recommendation of Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) which says to put production code  (which will be packaged into the resulting jar) into *src/main/java* whereas test code into *src/test/java*.

The problem you described having different dependencies sounds weired. The question is how have you tried to build a single moduel? This can usualy be achieved by using the following from the parent location:

```
mvn -pl module clean package
```

The problem with your unit tests sounds like a missing dependencies etc. but here is the questions how have you tried to run the unit tests and have you configured maven-surefire-plugin ? Or do you have integration tests? This is only a guess cause i don't see any configuration of Maven plugins in your poms.

Comment: There was something wrong in my configuration indeed, I edited the end of my question to explain what it was. Thanks